# How do you set a default value on lightning component force:inputField which is a lookup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup, aura-attribute, javascript-controller

I have a lightning component (Summer 16) which contains a "Task" attribute as follows:

```
    <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Task' }"/>
```

Further down the page, I have a force:inputField to allow the user to select the owner of the task as follows:

```
    <force:inputField value="{!v.task.OwnerId}" aura:id="OwnerId" />
```

This works great and allows me to select a user the lightning way.

[image: Simple User List]

However, I'd like to default this to the current user. I have tried setting it in the init event with no luck. The init event is firing, and I have retrieved the value after setting it and it is there. Static user id used for testing purposes only and it is a valid user id in our org.

```
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var tska = component.get("v.task");
        tska.OwnerId = '0054B000000XxeH';
        component.set("v.task", tska);
    }
```

I have also tried this code in the init method with no luck:

```
    component.find("OwnerId").set("v.value", "00561000001ZISx");
```

Now, if I create the attribute as follows, it does show it correctly:

```
    <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Task' , 'OwnerId': '0054B000000XxeH' }"/>
```

[image: Default User]

I tried setting the default dynamically with no luck. Any idea if this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: in init method you can call a apex method and get the Userinfo.getUserId() and set that value to task ownerId

Comment: have you tried creating the `<force:inputField  />` dynamically using the `$A.createComponent` by specifying the appropriate Id in the value attribute?

Comment: I did try setting it via an apex controller class, but same issue. That's why I went to a static id for testing.

Comment: It's not even letting me render a force:inputField dynamically. I was able to render a button, but not a force:inputField.

Comment: Maybe if you share the rest of your code, the code that sets the user, we can figure out where is the problem. Probably the issue resides there.

Comment: That code is above, in the init method. Basically, if I put a static id in the default of the attribute, it renders correctly. If I set the id via code it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Both the OwnerId and the Owner need to be populated...

```
var newTask = { 
    'sobjectType' : 'Task', 
    'OwnerId' : '0054B000000XxeH', 
    'Owner' : { 
         'sobjectType' : 'User',
         'Id' : '0054B000000XxeH',
         'Name' : 'Brett'
    }
 };
```

but you also need to manually set some values on the force:inputField to get it to display the Pill (this assumes the force:inputField has an aura:id="taskOwnerId")...

```
var valuesOwner = [{
                type : 'User',
                id: newTask.OwnerId,
                label: newTask.Owner.Name, 
                icon : {
                    url:'/img/icon/t4v35/standard/user_120.png',
                    backgroundColor:'65CAE4',
                    alt:'User'
                }, 
                record: newTask.Owner,
                placeHolder: 'Search Users'
            }];
component.find("taskOwnerId").get("v.body")[0].set("v.values", valuesOwner);
```

I'm not sure if this is supported but its working for me.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work any more due to lockerservice, unfortunately (or fortunately if you are keen to keep things secure :) )

Answer (score -2):

To set on the init function object values you should set it like the default json:

```
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    var strNewTask ='{ "sobjectType": "Task" , "OwnerId": "0054B000000XxeH" }';
    var newTask = JSON.parse(strNewTask);
    component.set("v.task", newTask);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. If I remove the default from the attribute itself, it shows a giant red error message (`Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
An internal server error has occurred`) and never even executes the init method. If I leave the default and run the code above it just renders an empty text input.